"How to implement a dynamic subtask input field with icons that change and subtasks list below?"
I'm trying to implement a dynamic subtask feature similar to what I've attached in the images below. Here's what I'm aiming for:
The input field has a + icon by default.
When the user starts typing in the input field, the + icon should change to X (cancel) and ✓ (confirm) buttons.
When the user confirms (✓), the entered text should be added as a subtask below the input field.
There should be options to edit (a pencil icon) and delete (a trash can icon) each added subtask.
I've attached screenshots for reference:



Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mre] so that the community may be able to help you.

What are you asking? How to structure that input in HTML? How to implement those dynamic features in JavaScript? Hot to add the icons in CSS? Please [edit] your question to focus it on one clearly identified issue.
